# How get selected listitems using linq - lambda syntax?

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda, checkboxlist

I'm using **VB.Net** and I would like to know how to get the selected checkboxes in a checkboxlist using **linq** and **lambda syntax** (not query syntax, repeat NO query syntax).

I tried this but it's definitely not right.

```
 cblRequired.Items.OfType(Of ListItem).Where(Function (i As ListItem ) i.Selected End Function)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use `cblRequired.SelectedItems`?

Comment: One, there is no SelectedItems. More importantly, it's not what I asked for.

Comment: Ah.  I thought you had said `CheckedListBox`.  That makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the only thing wrong with your code is that you should not have the `End Function`, since it's a single-line lambda expression.  This should work:

```
cblRequired.Items.OfType(Of ListItem).Where(Function(i As ListItem) i.Selected)
```

Technically, you don't need to specify the type of `i`, since it will automatically infer the type:

```
cblRequired.Items.OfType(Of ListItem).Where(Function(i) i.Selected)
```

If you want it to be a multi-line lamba expression, that would look like this:

```
cblRequired.Items.OfType(Of ListItem).Where(Function(i) 
                                                Return i.Selected
                                            End Function)
```